# Tierprices in product view - wrong price calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group, tierprice, view

I have a problem with the view of the tier prices. When customer group ID X have tier price for `6 pieces each 56,--.` The view show this:

[image: Tierpriceview]
 
 **The tierprices for all:**

```
6 pieces each 64,--
12 pieces each 61,--
```

In this case the tier price view should only show the 6 pieces.
Where is the problem?

Comment: check your product store level,it seems tier price is set for both quantity i.e. for 6 and 12.Also try to re-index price.

Comment: Thanks for response. Index is OK. Customer group ID have only one tierprice (6 each 56,--). In the view it shows the 12 pieces from all customers. In this case it should show only the 6 pieces or for 12 pieces the same price.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time the problem is still there. But I found a solution for me.

I put this code into tierprices.phtml:

```
<?php 
$preis1 = $_tierPrices[0][website_price];
$preis2 = $_tierPrices[1][website_price];
?>
<?php
if ($preis1 < $preis2):?>
<?php
unset($_tierPrices[1]);
?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And now only the first line is shown.